# Incremental SVN to Git migration of very large repositories

Tags: git, git-svn

We are trying to migrate our SVN repos to Git using the "git svn clone / git push" approach.

This is working fine whilst we run it in one "big bang".
But due to some long running migrations of very old and large repos, we need to split the migration in two steps.

How could we do this?

Comment: `git svn fetch --revision $FROM:$TO`